# Problems with my javascript program on the RPi

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and made a little program to control my RPi robot over the Wlan... But I got a problem. Every time when I hold W, A or D for a longer time, the robot goes crazy and doesn't want to stop and drives in one direction, until I press one of the other two keys. I can control the robot over the webinterface. Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script Language="Javascript">

window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp, false);
function set0()
{
document.location="cgi-bin/set0.cgi";
}
function set1()
{
document.location="cgi-bin/set1.cgi";
}
function set01()
{
document.location="cgi-bin/set01.cgi";
}
function clear01(event)
{
document.location="cgi-bin/clear01.cgi";
}

function onKeyDown(event){
var keyCode = event.keyCode;
switch(keyCode){
case 87:  //w
    set01();
break;
case 68:  //d
    set1();
break;
case 65:  //a
    set0();
break;
}
}
function onKeyUp(event){
var keyCode = event.keyCode;
switch(keyCode){
case 87:  //w
    clear01(event);
break;
case 68:  //d
    clear01(event);
break;
case 65: //a
    clear01(event);
break;
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align:center">
<h1>The PiRover</h1>

<img src="/forward.jpg" id="f" onmousedown="set01()" onmouseup="clear01(event)">
<br>
<img src="/left.jpg" id="l" onmousedown="set0()" onmouseup="clear01(event)">
<img src="/right.jpg" id="r" onmousedown="set1()" onmouseup="clear01(event)">
<br>
<img src="/stop.jpg" id="s" onmousedown="clear01(event)" onmouseup="clear01(event)">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What backend are you using? How it react to the press of a single key? maybe there are just a lot of command queued and waiting to be fulfilled.

Comment: By the way, you should be a little more specific, or your question can be addressed as too vague and closed

Comment: I am using a Windows powered laptop with Google Chrome. When I press a single key like W for a short time and release it the robot stops, but when I hold W for like 3 seconds the robot won't stop... :(

Comment: You're reloading the document when you press a key? That's hardly what you want.

Comment: Yeah, the document enables the motors. For example the document "set01" is forward and should be enabled when the key "W" is pressed down. After releasing the key, the document "clear01" should disable all the motors, but this doesn't work, when one of the keys have been activated for longer than a few seconds.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could paste the backend logic. Seems like problem is with backend